# Ejs как определить влезает ли таблица в документ и если не влезает добавить еще один?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

У меня есть ejs документ. Столбцы выделенные синим могут иметь разное количество строк и их может быть любое количество.
[image: Документ]

Я генерирую pdf из этого документа с помощью npm html-pdf

```
const pdf = require('html-pdf')
const ejs = require('ejs')

pdf.create(ejs.render(тут_ejs_строка), {/* опции html-pdf */}).toFile(path, function(err, res) {
    if (err) return console.log(err)
})
```

Как определить, что таблица не влазит в документ и создать еще один, а потом еще один и т.д.?

Буду благодарен любой помощи, естественно не прошу готовое решение

Answer (score 0):

Уверен, разбивать таблицу на несколько страниц - это задача библиотеки pdf. Если в библиотеке нет функции типа "перенести таблицу", то вам придется сделать это вручную. Например, спарсить результат `ejs.render` (Я так понимаю, вам нужны данные строк таблицы? Можете спарсить строки, используя `jQuery`).

Затем вычислите, на какой строчке нужно переносить таблицу (для каждой ячейки посчитайте высоту в строчках (длина строковых данных в ячейке/длина ячейки в символах), max высота из ячеек в строке = высота строки), и создайте в pdf новую страницу с оставшимися строками.